# Matplotlib - User changes amount of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, axis, figure

In my code the user should be able to change the amount of subplots in the figure. So first there are two subplots:

[image]

I use following code:

```
ax1 = figure.add_sublots(2,1,1)
ax2 = figure.add_sublots(2,1,2)
```

If the plus button is pressed one subplot shall be added:

[image]

How should I do this? Is there a command like

```
ax1.change_subplot(3,1,1)
ax2.change_subplot(3,1,2)
ax3 = figure.add_sublots(3,1,3)
```

or do I have to delete all subplots and redraw them (which I would like to avoid)?

Comment: This documentation might help https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot

Comment: I know this doc. It's not written there or I don't understand it. One can add plots but not change the position of existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was looking for is:

```
ax1.change_geometry(3,1,1)
```

With this command it is possible to rearrange the sublots.
I found this solution here:
[Dynamically add subplots in matplotlib with more than one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575399/dynamically-add-subplots-in-matplotlib-with-more-than-one-column)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option. You can create a new GridSpec for each number of subplots you want to show and set the position of the axes according to that gridspec.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class VariableGrid():
    def __init__(self,fig):
        self.fig = fig
        self.axes = []
        self.gs = None
        self.n = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.n > 0:
            for i,ax in zip(range(self.n), self.axes):
                ax.set_position(self.gs[i-1].get_position(self.fig))
                ax.set_visible(True)

            for j in range(len(self.axes),self.n,-1 ):
                print(self.n, j)
                self.axes[j-1].set_visible(False)
        else:
            for ax in self.axes:
                ax.set_visible(False)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


    def add(self, evt=None):
        self.n += 1
        self.gs= GridSpec(self.n,1)
        if self.n > len(self.axes):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(self.gs[self.n-1])
            self.axes.append(ax)
        self.update()

    def sub(self, evt=None):
        self.n = max(self.n-1,0)
        if self.n > 0:
            self.gs= GridSpec(self.n,1)
        self.update()


fig = plt.figure()

btn_ax1 = fig.add_axes([.8,.02,.05,.05])
btn_ax2 = fig.add_axes([.855,.02,.05,.05])
button_add =Button(btn_ax1, "+")
button_sub =Button(btn_ax2, "-")


grid = VariableGrid(fig)
button_add.on_clicked(grid.add)
button_sub.on_clicked(grid.sub)

plt.show()
```

[image]