# matplotlib dynamic number of subplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to get a subplot using `matplotlib`, with number of `subplots` calculated in runtime (as `pnum` varies in the example below)

```
  pnum = len(args.m)
  f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(pnum, sharex=True, sharey=True)
  ax1.plot(x,ptp, "#757578",label="Total")
  ax2.fill_between(x,dxyp,facecolor="C0", label="$d_{xy}$")
```

This example, obviously, only work, when pnum=2. So, I need to do some thing else.

I have checked the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319796/dynamically-add-create-subplots-in-matplotlib), but this is plotting same thing in all the plots.

Comment: So how would you determine what should be plotted to each subplot if not by using a loop, like in the linked question?

Answer (score 2):

To create a dynamic number of subplots you may decide not to specify the axes individually, but as an axes array

```
pnum = len(args.m)
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(pnum, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

`ax_arr` is then a numpy array.
You can then do something for each axes in a loop.

```
for ax in ax_arr.flatten():
    ax.plot(...)
```

Comment: where `ax_arr` is a list?