# Add Axessubplot object to specific subplot index

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

There is an easy way to generate word frequency plots with NLTK:

```
my_plot = nltk.FreqDist(some_dynamically_changing_list[0]).plot(20)
```

`some_dynamically_changing_list` contains a list of texts that I want to see the word frequency for. The resulting `my_plot` is an `AxesSubplot` object. I want to be able to take this object and directly insert it to a dynamically sized subplotted grid. The closest I've gotten to the solution after scouring SO and Google is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41385215/2897989). However, I have an issue because I don't want to use plt's `plot` function. So for example I'd have a dynamic subplot grid:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tot = len(some_dynamically_changing_list)
cols = 5
rows = tot // cols 

if tot % cols != 0:
    rows += 1
    
position = range(1, tot + 1)

fig = plt.figure()
for k in range(tot):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, position[k])

    my_plot = nltk.FreqDist(some_dynamically_changing_list[k]).plot(20)
    ax.plot(my_plot) #This is where I have my issue.
```

Of course this won't work, as `ax.plot` expects data, not a plot. But I want to plug my `my_plot` into that specific slot. How can I do that (if I can)?

Comment: You can't "take" a subplot and place it somewhere.  When creating the plot, it already needs to be on the correct spot.  Most functions that create plots allow an `ax=` parameter, so maybe in this case you could try `nltk.FreqDist(...).plot(..., ax=ax)`?   Further, most such functions create the plot on the "current subplot", which in your case would be already set via `fig.add_subplot`. Are you sure you are using the latest github version of `nltk`?

Comment: Looking into the [source code]((https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/f989fe65d421e7ea4d1037a00f07eaeee3ad6a29/nltk/probability.py#L247-L249), `nltk`'s `plot` doesn't support an `ax=` parameter, but does use `plt.gca()` to make sure it draws on the "current ax" (the currently active subplot). Anyway, you should remove `ax.plot(my_plot)` as such a thing doesn't make sense in matplotlib.